# any way that I can use to load the admin panel of a WordPress to an iframe?

Tags: wordpress, iframe

Is there any way that I can use to load the admin panel of a WordPress to an iframe that is embaded in a different site?

For example, the iframe URL of a WordPress site is https://www.example.com/wp-admin and I want to load in in a iframe which is added on a different site, https://www.app.com/.

Is that possible?
How?

I have tired by adding the following...

```
function add_cors_http_header() {
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" );
    header( "Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *" );
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_cors_http_header' );
```

It keeps redirecting to the login page.